Database size when attaching image in civimail
I just would like to make sure I have the correct understanding of what happens when adding an image or an attachment to a Civimail / mass mailing, let's say sent to 500 contacts.
I have CKEditor5 installed and configured with "uploaded images" (instead of embedded images)
Until now, I have asked our users to avoid attaching files and images in civimail, because I was worried about the impact on the database size.
Are the following statements correct ?

when adding an image inline in the email body, by using the toolbar icon "add an image or file" : there is no impact on the database size. The file is stored once in the file system, and NOT 500 times in the database


Embedding the image in the email body by a "copy paste" operation has a severe impact on the database : the image is stored 500 times

using the "attachments" button in civimail has the same impact as in option 1) above
: the file is stored only once



Is all of the above correct ?

I have never tried but I think you are correct.
